# Using shared_ptr with char*

Tags: c++, c++11

I can not create:

```
shared_ptr<char> n_char = make_shared<char>(new char[size_]{});
```

How can I create

```
char* chr = new char[size_]{};
```

using modern pointers?

Comment: Btw you better use `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` instead.

Comment: @Slava, well, those are equivalent to `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`. `std::string` used to be shared, copy-on-write in some versions of the standard library, but it turned out not to work for some cases, so it now always has a unique pointer underneath. If you want shared, you need to do it yourself (and be careful about modifying).

Comment: @JanHudec if you need shared ownership then use `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<char>>` or `std::shared_ptr<std::array<char,N>>` as you have to keep track of the buffer size anyway.

Comment: @Slava, not necessarily. A shared buffer, done the simple way, needs to be read-only and then if it is NUL-terminated, you don't need separate length (if you do need length, `shared_ptr<string>` makes a lot more sense).

Comment: @JanHudec then it could be `std::string` and you do not need to use explicit deleter, which is easy to miss and get UB, and you can use `std::make_shared` as well.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> shared_ptr n_char = make_shared(new char[size_]{});

`make_shared` calls `new` inside, so you never use both. In this case you only call `new`, because `make_shared` does not work for arrays.

However, you still need to make it call the right delete:

**Before C++17**:

You need to specify the deleter explicitly.

```
std::shared_ptr<char> ptr(new char[size_], std::default_delete<char[]>());
```

**Since C++17**:

`shared_ptr` gains array support similar to what `unique_ptr` already had from the beginning:

```
std::shared_ptr<char[]> ptr(new char[size_]);
```

---

Be aware that done this simple way you are not tracking length and in multi-threaded environment not synchronizing. If you need the buffer modifiable, making shared pointer to `std::string`, or struct with `std::string` and `std::mutex` in it, will add a level of indirection, but will be otherwise more convenient to use.

Comment: Actually, `make_shared` _is_ a wrapper of `new`. The term "wrapper" generally means that the wrapper function has an implementation which calls the wrapped function, and `make_shared` indeed calls `new`. That's precisely why you _don't_ pass `new char[]` as an argument, that would be a second call to `new`.

Comment: @MSalters, ok, rewritten to avoid that term.

Comment: is this `shared_ptr<char*> var (new char[size_] {}, std::default_delete<char*>());` correct form?

Comment: @Person.Junkie, no; what you wrote is a shared pointer to a *pointer-to*-array, i.e. it's underlying type is `char **` (and second parameter is pointless since it is equal to default). The form in the answer is correct form for shared pointer to an array.

Comment: @JanHudec Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You could use `std::default_delete` specialized for arrays

```
std::shared_ptr<char> ptr(new char[size_], std::default_delete<char[]>());
```

See [std::default_delete docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete). While std::unique_ptr uses default_delete by default when no other deleter is specified and has a partial specialization that handles array types:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> ptr(new char[size_]);
```

With std::shared_ptr you need to select it manually by passing a deleter to the constructor.

Edit: Thanks to Jan Hudec, [c++17 includes a partial specialization for array types](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0497r0.html) as well:

```
std::shared_ptr<char[]> ptr(new char[size_]);  // c++17
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to separate **declaration** from **definition** you could use the following:

(tried to demonstrate a simple example with different pointer types and different custom deleters )

```
   class A
{

public:
    A(const char* const name_)
    {
        size_t len = std::strlen(name_) + 1;


        //Definition
    
        //ptr_name 
        this->ptr_name = 
            std::shared_ptr<char[]>(new char[len], [](char* p)-> void {delete[] p; });
        strcpy_s(this->ptr_name.get(),len,name_);
        //ptr_buffer
        this->ptr_buffer = 
            std::shared_ptr<int[]>(new int[SIZE] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, std::default_delete<int[]>());

    }
    void Print()
    {
        std::cout << "Print name " << std::endl;
        std::cout << this->ptr_name << '\n';
        std::cout << "Print buffer " << std::endl;
        for (int i=0; i< SIZE; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << this->ptr_buffer[i] << '\n';
        }
    }
private:
    //Declaration
    std::shared_ptr<char[]> ptr_name;
    std::shared_ptr<int[]> ptr_buffer;
public:
    const static size_t SIZE = 5;

};
void func(A object)
{
    
    object.Print();
}
int main()
{

    const char* str = "Hello World!";
    A a(str);
    func(a);
    a.Print();

    
}
```

Answer (score -3):

For simple char buffer:

```
std::shared_ptr<char> ptr( (char*)operator new( buffer_size_here ) );
```